# Keycloak Auth API throws CORS error from static HTML page

Tags: nginx, cors, keycloak

**The ask:**
Setup auth guard from nginx for our APIs and redirect to Keycloak for unauthorized requests.

**The issue:**
When hitting the restricted API from a static HTML page (via fetch / HTTP client for angular) served by NGINX, Keycloak Auth API throws a CORS error saying the requested URL doesn't pass the preflight policy due to missing Allow-origin header.
[image: CORS error thrown when redirected from nginx]

The same API when hit directly from the browser works as expected and we are able to redirect to the KeyCloak Login page successfully. Here are the response headers for this page:
[image: KC auth API's response headers]

Web Origins has been set to '*' for our Client in Keycloak. But we don't see any of the expected response headers above.

Nginx conf for redirect:

```
location /api/ {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization, Content-Type';
                    # Keycloak integration
        auth_request /keycloak_auth;
        auth_request_set $auth_status $upstream_status;

        error_page 401 = @handle_auth;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location @handle_auth {
        return 302 http://localhost:8080/realms/DP/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=agamin&response_type=code&state=asdsad1;
    }

    location = /keycloak_auth {
        internal;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization, Content-Type';
        proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization, Content-Type';
        add_header X-debug-message1.1 'initiating token check' always;
        proxy_method POST;
        proxy_set_header Authorization "bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJvamZPdTdXQlJIX2dzQlU1RC0tVG0tUlNMbG9RVHUyd2liN0tDSkVkalBNIn0.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.U9nat76C9wf2KDmBOkB2cv5opBdfUQ4AXsRIBg9toPZISs8bdzUtsuHplXhZLngiDUj2GdsqZIK0sqOctU2gut_pIaFWvgYDgJXrkakJIdlsPP_yJ1vjeJ9-fwubPMZ4LzIxpKjPIzvoX_wkcO-ZM6TfaQZUUrElCbUWE073gdTt-gGaKn4im9hZ0gR8-8TZELJnz4Xe30GKWC17BmkU988cRAl8OpnoCwNYbN9h2B1DX0pelzFcO38McUR7DdQxD62w7RQdc46wu6ztJs1MYiS9MRVps4rcM2JeezMaYhY9W0D9lYxK5Lb34kQLGAAwqVmx0GcTdr8rC-whBexxYg";
        proxy_set_header Content-Type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        proxy_set_body "client_id='agamin'";
        proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/realms/DP/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo;
    }
```

Keycloak Version: 20.x, 21.x, 22.x
JDK: OpenJDK14

CORS requests need to be fulfilled by the KC server and we have set the required values for WebOrigins and Redirect URLs but we still observe that the required headers are missing in API response.

Any insights will be much appreciated!